# React Native Operation Not Permitted

Tags: android, facebook, react-native

I am following the simply setup of React Native at: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html,
After setting up the environment with `react-native start`, and running `react-native run-android`, I receive the following errors:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:_debugCompile'.
   > Could not find com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1.
     Searched in the following locations:
         file:/C:/Users/KJA/.m2/repository/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/23.0
.1/appcompat-v7-23.0.1.pom
         file:/C:/Users/KJA/.m2/repository/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/23.0
.1/appcompat-v7-23.0.1.jar
         https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/23.0.1/app
compat-v7-23.0.1.pom
         https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/23.0.1/app
compat-v7-23.0.1.jar
         file:/C:/Users/KJA/ReactNativeProjects/AwesomeProject/node_modules/reac
t-native/android/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/23.0.1/appcompat-v7-23.0.1.pom

         file:/C:/Users/KJA/ReactNativeProjects/AwesomeProject/node_modules/reac
t-native/android/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/23.0.1/appcompat-v7-23.0.1.jar

         file:/C:/Android/android-sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/su
pport/appcompat-v7/23.0.1/appcompat-v7-23.0.1.pom
         file:/C:/Android/android-sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/su
pport/appcompat-v7/23.0.1/appcompat-v7-23.0.1.jar
         file:/C:/Android/android-sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/android/sup
port/appcompat-v7/23.0.1/appcompat-v7-23.0.1.pom
         file:/C:/Android/android-sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/android/sup
port/appcompat-v7/23.0.1/appcompat-v7-23.0.1.jar
     Required by:
         AwesomeProject:app:unspecified
         AwesomeProject:app:unspecified > com.facebook.react:react-native:0.23.1

   > Could not find com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.0.1.
     Searched in the following locations:
         file:/C:/Users/KJA/.m2/repository/com/android/support/recyclerview-v7/2
3.0.1/recyclerview-v7-23.0.1.pom
         file:/C:/Users/KJA/.m2/repository/com/android/support/recyclerview-v7/2
3.0.1/recyclerview-v7-23.0.1.jar
         https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/recyclerview-v7/23.0.1/
recyclerview-v7-23.0.1.pom
         https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/recyclerview-v7/23.0.1/
recyclerview-v7-23.0.1.jar
         file:/C:/Users/KJA/ReactNativeProjects/AwesomeProject/node_modules/reac
t-native/android/com/android/support/recyclerview-v7/23.0.1/recyclerview-v7-23.0
.1.pom
         file:/C:/Users/KJA/ReactNativeProjects/AwesomeProject/node_modules/reac
t-native/android/com/android/support/recyclerview-v7/23.0.1/recyclerview-v7-23.0
.1.jar
         file:/C:/Android/android-sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/su
pport/recyclerview-v7/23.0.1/recyclerview-v7-23.0.1.pom
         file:/C:/Android/android-sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/su
pport/recyclerview-v7/23.0.1/recyclerview-v7-23.0.1.jar
         file:/C:/Android/android-sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/android/sup
port/recyclerview-v7/23.0.1/recyclerview-v7-23.0.1.pom
         file:/C:/Android/android-sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/android/sup
port/recyclerview-v7/23.0.1/recyclerview-v7-23.0.1.jar
     Required by:
         AwesomeProject:app:unspecified > com.facebook.react:react-native:0.23.1
```

and within the `Running Packager:`

```
React packager ready.

[11:12:35 PM] <END>   Crawling File System (17042ms)
[11:12:35 PM] <START> Building in-memory fs for JavaScript
[11:12:35 PM] <END>   Building in-memory fs for JavaScript (141ms)
[11:12:35 PM] <START> Building in-memory fs for Assets
[11:12:35 PM] <END>   Building in-memory fs for Assets (132ms)
[11:12:35 PM] <START> Building Haste Map
[11:12:35 PM] <START> Building (deprecated) Asset Map
[11:12:35 PM] <END>   Building (deprecated) Asset Map (46ms)
[11:12:35 PM] <END>   Building Haste Map (275ms)
[11:12:35 PM] <END>   Building Dependency Graph (17591ms)
 ERROR  EPERM: operation not permitted, lstat 'C:\Users\KJA\ReactNativeProjects\
AwesomeProject\node_modules\.staging\utf-8-validate-def6dc62\src\validation.cc'
{"errno":-4048,"code":"EPERM","syscall":"lstat","path":"C:\\Users\\KJA\\ReactNat
iveProjects\\AwesomeProject\\node_modules\\.staging\\utf-8-validate-def6dc62\\sr
c\\validation.cc"}
Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, lstat 'C:\Users\KJA\ReactNativeProjects\A
wesomeProject\node_modules\.staging\utf-8-validate-def6dc62\src\validation.cc'
    at Error (native)
```

How can I alleviate this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you're missing android support library:

```
> Could not find com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1.
```

Double check your packages on Android SDK Manager, and make sure you have installed all of the following:
[Android SDK Manager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pQ9OG.png)

Hope it helps! :)

Comment: Yes, apparently two years ago the filepath for my Android SDK was moved from `C:\...` to my `C:\Users\...AppData...` folder, therefore the libraries were all outdated by about 2 years when looking at `C:/Android/android-sdk/extras/android/m2repository/...`. Thank you